# Why does `Meteor.findOne()` return a different ID each time?

Tags: meteor

I am building an instant messaging application as part of the [Coursera responsive web development course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/web-application-development/home/week/4) with Dr. Matthew Yee-King. The project is [here](https://github.com/xiongtx/mInstant/tree/f7c196506d98cf8677ddaa79039bb118f7eecafc); I have linked to a specific commit for posterity.

I have a collection,`Chats`, that contains `Chat` [objects](https://github.com/xiongtx/mInstant/blob/f7c196506d98cf8677ddaa79039bb118f7eecafc/app/lib/Chat.js#L3). that I am publishing to the client.

The `autopublish` and `insecure` packages have been removed, so I am publishing the collection from server to client with [the following](https://github.com/xiongtx/mInstant/blob/f7c196506d98cf8677ddaa79039bb118f7eecafc/app/server/publish.js#L4):

```
Meteor.publish("chats", function(){
    return Chats.find({$or: [{user1: Meteor.userId},
                             {user2: Meteor.userId}]});
});
```

The client subscribes to the collection with [the following](https://github.com/xiongtx/mInstant/blob/f7c196506d98cf8677ddaa79039bb118f7eecafc/app/client/subscribe.js#L2):

```
Meteor.subscribe("chats");
```

When I access the `Chats` object on the server through `meteor mongo` with `db.chats.findOne()`, I get an object with an ID.

When I access it on the client (Chrome 47) console with `Chats.findOne()`, I get an object with the same property values, except for `_id`, which is **different each time I invoke the command**!

What is wrong here? I should be getting the same `_id` as the server, right?

Comment: `.findOne()` doesn't guarantee order.

Comment: But I only have one document in the collection.

Comment: Then there can only be one _id

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the [publish function](https://github.com/xiongtx/mInstant/blob/f7c196506d98cf8677ddaa79039bb118f7eecafc/app/server/publish.js#L5):

```
Meteor.publish("chats", function(){
    return Chats.find({$or: [{user1: Meteor.userId},
                             {user2: Meteor.userId}]});
});
```

First of all, `Meteor.userId()` is a function. Secondly, the documentation notes that `Meteor.userId()` is available everywhere *except* in publish functions.

Instead, `this.userId` [should be used](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/publish_userId) in publish functions.